# format json information from url parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Hi I am starting in `json` and `php`, and i have a problem, i have this encode `json` from `php`

```
    [{
    "profesional_id": "76317897",
    "profesional_profesion": "Teacher",
    "profesional_foto": "sdwsgted.jpg",
    "profesional_nombre": "Michael",
    "profesional_apellidos": "Tyler",
    "profesional_calificacion": "5"
}, {
    "profesional_id": "34328602",
    "profesional_profesion": "Doctor",
    "profesional_foto": "jsjdfls.jpg",
    "profesional_nombre": "Allison",
    "profesional_apellidos": "Adney",
    "profesional_calificacion": "5"
}]
```

i am trying formating to have something like this

[See sample imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjUT4.jpg)

I find this, for table format is ok

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url="../ajax/profesional.php?op=listar";
    $("#tablajson tbody").html("");
    $.getJSON(url,function(profesionales){
        $.each(profesionales, function(i,profesional){
            var newRow =
                "<tr>"
                +"<td>"+profesional.profesional_id+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+profesional.profesional_profesion+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+profesional.profesional_foto+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+profesional.profesional_nombre+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+profesional.profesional_apellidos+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+profesional.profesional_calificacion+"</td>"
                +"</tr>";
            $(newRow).appendTo("#tablajson tbody");
        });
    });
});
```

and something like this is the format i need

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card team__item">
        <img src="demo/img/contacts/profesional_foto" class="team__img" alt="">

        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">profesional_nombre profesional_apellido</h4>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle">profesional_profesion</h6>


            <p class="card-text">profesional_another info</p>

            <div class="rating-demo">
                <div class="rating" data-rateyo-star-width="20px" data-rating="profesional_calificacion"></div>
            </div>

            <BR>

            <button class="btn btn-outline-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-backdrop-ignore">Solicitar cita</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i do it, almost all the info i find use tables.

Thanks a lot

Comment: So... what's your problem exactly?

Comment: If you're looking to use `php` to generate your final HTML code, you shouldn't be making AJAX requests for JSON code. You should use a client-side template like `mustache js` to generate your final HTML based on JSON data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am trying get someting like image from a json info, i don´t know about mustache, looks good i´ll read about it

Comment: we don't see your image!

Comment: @prodisoft can you tell me that what is an issue with table layout and why do you want to use div layout?

Comment: I have a json obtained from a url ../ajax/profesional.php?op=listar, i catch the info in table layout, but i am trying change the table layout to the divs code sample in post, something like the link image in the post is what i am searching. i have problems to jump from table layout to divs